# MVC HTML email template

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-email

Razor does not work in html email template; 
This produces  the image:

```
*<img style="border: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display: block;max-width: 600px" src="http://xxx.xx.uk/off-line/email-template-images/banner.jpg" alt="http://xxxx.xx.uk/off-line/email-template-images/banner.jpg" width="600" height="229">*
```

This does not:

```
*<img style="border: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display: block;max-width: 600px" src="@ViewBag.imageurl" alt="http://xxxx.xx.uk/off-line/email-template-images/banner.jpg" width="600" height="229">*
```

Note razor in SRC.
How can I render the image using a reference from the controller?

Comment: Check out http://aboutcode.net/postal/.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Postal MVC, but src="@ViewBag.imageurl" does not work.

Comment: Postal doesn't have a `ViewBag`. The whole point is to pass a strongly-typed `Email` subclass to the view with whatever data you need on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) for this task. It allows you to use Razor outside of MVC.
There is a tutorial [here](http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-introduction/).

An example might be:

```
string email = "Hello @Model.Name! Thanks for registering.";
string body = Razor.Parse(email, new { Name = "Bob Smith" });
```